# convert eye-tracking .edf file to ASC/CSV format

Tags: python, converters, psychopy, eye-tracking

I have a recording of tracking data in .edf format (SR-RESEARCH eyelink). I want to convert it to ASC/CSV format in python. I have the GUI application but I want to do it programmatically (in Python).
I found the package pyEDFlib but couldn't find an example to how convert the eye-tracking .edf file to .asc or .csv.

What will the best best way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: what format is the data in an .edf file? is it text or binary?

Comment: Unless you are doing this strictly for learning purposes you will spend a lot of time re-inventing the wheel. Just use sr-research's converter program, and then spend your python programming time parsing the asc file where you can more easily see what you are doing. You could still call the conversion script from within your python script. Here is the link to their program if you don't have it: http://download.sr-support.com/dispdoc/page25.html

Comment: @oren Did you manage to sort it out?

Comment: @Bentaye I wrote some parser myself that should be good enough for my needs, Thanks!

Comment: pyEDFlib is for the "European Data Format" (Electroencephalography data files) ... you are looking for the "Eyelink Data Format" (Eyetracking data files). pyEDFlib will not help you.

Answer (score 3):

If I trust the page here: http://pyedflib.readthedocs.io/en/latest, you can run through all the signals in the file this way:

```
import pyedflib
import numpy as np

f = pyedflib.EdfReader("data/test_generator.edf")
n = f.signals_in_file
signal_labels = f.getSignalLabels()
sigbufs = np.zeros((n, f.getNSamples()[0]))
for i in np.arange(n):
    sigbufs[i, :] = f.readSignal(i)
```

The `pyEDFlib` library simply reads the file into an EdfReader object.
Then you just need to go through and make row for each.

I assume that `signal_labels` (in the code above) will be an array with all the labels so make a comma separated string out of them

```
signal_labels_row = ",".join(signal_labels)
```

Then do the same for each signal, 1 comma separated String for each

Then simply write them in a file.

I can see they provide an example of how to read a file and extract all the data you need here
https://github.com/holgern/pyedflib/blob/master/demo/readEDFFile.py

Comment: EyeLink / SR Research EDF File is not compatible with the https://www.edfplus.info/specs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answers i have created this python3 script to export all singnals to multiple .csv files https://github.com/folkien/pyEdfToCsv

Comment: @paszko Can you add some documentation or examples to the readme?

Comment: Added example to repo.