# How to convert .edf file into csv file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, mne-python

I need a python program to convert edf file into csv file. I didn't find any helping material from internet. Actually due to some reasons it is compulsory to convert edf file into csv format. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48784257/convert-eye-tracking-edf-file-to-asc-csv-format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert eye-tracking .edf file to ASC/CSV format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48784257/convert-eye-tracking-edf-file-to-asc-csv-format)

Answer (score 2):

In MNE-Python:

```
import numpy as np
import mne
edf = mne.io.read_raw_edf('your_edf_file.edf')
header = ','.join(edf.ch_names)
np.savetxt('your_csv_file.csv', edf.get_data().T, delimiter=',', header=header)
```

The resulting CSV file will be big! The first line is the "header" and contains the names of each channel. Each following line is a time-point with the voltage recorded at each channel.